# How to get NFCID2 of android device itself?

Tags: android

I want to know how to get Felica IDm (NFCID2) of android device itself.

I can read NFCID2 of the Android device by using other Felica reader.
And Android device can read Felica information with TAG_DISCOVERED intent.

But I can't found API to get NFCID2 of device itself.
Is it impossible?
If anyone knows anything, please let me know.